# time now in Riyadh (KSA) , by javascript

Tags: javascript

How are you ?

I want to add block in site about time now in Riyadh (+3 time zone) (Capital of saudi arabia)

for example when the visitor from Germany or Spain come to my site , he wants to know the time in Riyadh , how can show the time now in Riyadh .

also I want the time 12h ( 12:10:25 am ) ..

Thank you very much for helping me ..

Comment: [The MDN Date documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: I don't know about javascript plaese help me , and give me the code for my request ..

Comment: I guess we need to bring the `plz-give-me-teh-codes` tag back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the UTC time by adding the offset returned by [`getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). This is in minutes so you can see I convert it to milliseconds for the adding. Once you have the UTC time, simply add the offset for the time zone of your choice.

```
var d = new Date();
var local = d.getTime();
var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * (60 * 1000);
var utc = new Date(local + offset);
var riyadh = new Date(utc.getTime() + (3 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
alert(riyadh.toString());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nddf7/

The `riyadh` variable holds a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object for Riyadh. You can then use the link Pointy provided and integrate this into your page.